# How would I make sense of the answer choices for solutions to a rational equation?

Tags: rational-functions

I am trying to find all of the asymptotes of a rational function, and the answer choices I am given are confusing. Because the degree of the function in the numerator was greater than the degree of the function in the denominator, I divided the numerator by the denominator using synthetic division to get the slant asymptote.

**Rational Function**
$f(x) = \frac{x^2 +4x+3}{x-2}$

**After dividing by x=2 (or (x-2))**
$y=2x+8$

**Answer Choices**

A. $y=x+6, x=2$

B. $x=-x=-3$

C. $y=1, x=2$

D. $y=x+6, x=-2$

[image: Image of the question]

Comment: These answers are not asymptotes, most of them are only individual points?

Comment: @Jalog_the_Martian There was a typesetting problem. (Fixed, but there is still a missing value in B.)

Comment: Even now C is still just a point, I think the original author needs to carefully rewrite the question as even with your clean typesetting the options are messy. However I shall attempt an answer ignoring the options

Comment: @Jalog_the_Martian While it is not clear, I believe that we are meant to interpret each equation as a line in the plane.  Thus  (C) corresponds to the horizontal line $y=1$ and the vertical line $x=2$ (meaning that the function has a vertical 'tote at $x=2$, and a horizontal 'tote at $y=1$).

Comment: Ah yeah, that does make sense. Well spotted.

Comment: The original text of the question had $x = -x = 3$ for (B), which would be vertical asymptotes at $x=\pm 3$, I think.  I've made that edit.

Comment: I now added the image of the question to show the equation. Sorry for the misformatting

Comment: I think option c should be two lines, $x=-1$ and $x=3$. The equation $x=-x$ is really just the line $x=0$, and the set $x=-x=3$ is empty.

Comment: @1Rock I think that there are commas or spacing missing in that problem. It is *really* poorly presented.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to follow your options but let us simply discuss the asymptotes.

You have made a mistake in your synthetic division. For $ x \to ±\infty$ You should get this:
$$ \textrm{lim}_{x \to ±\infty} f(x)= \textrm{lim}_{x \to ±\infty} \frac{(x+6)(x-2)+15}{x-2} =\textrm{lim}_{x \to ±\infty} \frac{(x+6)(x-2)}{x-2}  + \textrm{lim}_{x \to ±\infty} \frac{15}{x-2} \\ = x+6 $$

So the slant asymptote is $y=x+6$.

Now we also have a horizontal asymptote when the denominator is $0$. This simply given by $x-2=0 \implies x=2$.